# Is there a way to integrate $\int \frac{1}{f'(x)}dx$?

Tags: calculus

Is there a way to integrate $1/f'(x)$ with regards to $x$, where $f'(x)$ is the first derivative of $f(x)$? Are there any rules/conditions which make it possible?

Comment: No. No differentiation rule makes $f'$ appear at the denominator.

Answer (score 3):

Not in general, no. For example, if $f(x)=x\ln x-x$ we need [a special function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function).